# Delegate/Live Failure. Can't bind events after Prepending an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

EDIT--- I realized that the problem here was that the click handler that was bound to the element had to be unbound before I could bind another click handler handler.

I want to allow the user to select/unselect items by click on the element in question.  The elements start in an "options" box and if clicked, move to a "selected box".  If they are then clicked in the selected box, the elements move back to the original options box.

Can't figure out why delegate() and live() are not working here.  I assume this has to do with prependTo() or appendTo().

```
  $('#amen_options .options p').click(function(e){
      $(this).appendTo('#amen_selected .options');
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
});

/*  
$("body").delegate('#amen_selected p', 'click', function(e){
    #(this).appendTo('#amen_options .options');
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});
*/
$('div#amen_selected div.options p').live('click',function(e){
    $(this).appendTo('#amen_options .options');
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Here's the markup:

```
  <div>
   <div id="amen_options">
        <h3>Click to Select</h3>
        <div class="options">
            <p data-option="">One</p>
            <p data-option="">Two</p>
            <p data-option="">Etc...</p>
                 </div>
   </div>
   <div id="amen_selected"> 
        <h3>Selected</h3>
        <div class="options">
        </div>
   </div>
```

The first click works (sending p elements from options to selected box).  Once in selected, though, no event handlers are binding.  The firebug console isn't showing an error.  Normally, I'd assume that this is a markup problem, but I've checked it repeatedly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `delegate()` works good.

http://jsfiddle.net/fLXgU/1/

```
$('body').delegate('#amen_options .options p', 'click', function(e) {
    $(this).appendTo('#amen_selected .options');
    return false;
});
$('body').delegate('#amen_selected .options p', 'click', function(e) {
    $(this).appendTo('#amen_options .options');
    return false;
});
```